# Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to debug my project on my device and am having errors building it on the device. This is what the error shows on my terminal:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_local_notifications:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Do you get any result after typing `java` on terminal, if not try to set java+environment path